# How to split a string using a dynamic lenght?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = {'Goals': {0: '0,0,0,0', 1: '0,0', 2: '0,0,0,0,0,0', 3: '0,0', 4: '0,0'},
 'Devices': {0: 'mobile,mobile,mobile,mobile',
  1: 'mobile,mobile',
  2: 'mobile,mobile,mobile,mobile,mobile,mobile',
  3: 'mobile,mobile',
  4: 'mobile,mobile'},
 'Channels': {0: 'Paid Social,Paid Social,Paid Social,Paid Social',
  1: 'Paid Social,Paid Social',
  2: 'Paid Search,Paid Search,Paid Search,Paid Search,Paid Search,Paid Search',
  3: 'Display,Display',
  4: 'Referral,Referral'}}
```

This is what I am trying

```
df['New column'] = df['Devices'].str[0:df['Channels'].str.index(',')]
```

I am trying to get part of a string to create a new column working with pandas but the cut needs to be dynamic so I am using the function index to get the len of the string that I need, however when I run the code showed above I just get a column full of NaN. Could someone explain me what is exactly happening, I did a test using variables instead of plain numbers and it actually works but when I used pandas inside of the str function the code does not returns the result that I want.

Comment: `df['Devices'].str.split(',')`?

Comment: Thanks, but that would just split till the comma what I whant is to get the string depending on the index of the comma in anothet column, so I need to use another column as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of accomplishing this, easily enough. The first thing to note is that simply accessing `.str` and then doing `.split` (or the indexing operation you're doing currently) is not enough; neither of these functions allow you to pass in a series.

The first option would be to use a `.apply` function, in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Devices': ['123,123', '1234,123'], 'index': [3, 4]})

def split(row):
    return row['string_column'][0:row['index']]

df['new_string_column'] = df.apply(split, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nathan it was exactly what I needed, I tried something similar before but it did not work, I would consider the apply function more often, it is quite useful in this cases. Also congratulations for your development is quite cool, I thought of  how cool it would be to have the possibilitie to transfer excel formulas into pandas since they are a perfect complement, it is cool to see that someone is making it possible. I signed up for a trial! :D